# WebDriver - is it possible to use Firefox or IE javascript engine when using HtmlUnitDriver using .NET Selenium bindings?

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver

I am running into inconsistent behaviour when running my test using DesiredCapabilities.Firefox() vs. DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnitWithJavaScript().

For the most part, my issue lies with  DOM elements not appearing on the page when they should be there.

I've used a number of different strategies for "Wait"-ing for said element, but still, HtmlUnit driver seems to think that the element is not visible.

With that said, I am now asking if it's possible to run HtmlUnit providing a Firefox or IE handle; similar to how Java's HtmlUnitDriver implementation works:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);
```

Answer (score 0):

try WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());